# Best way of including Unit Tests in a C++ open source project?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, open-source

I'm planning to release a C++ project I've been working on as my first open source project. I use GTest as my unit test framework, and I don't know what's the common procedure to include this dependency in a public project.

Right now I have GTest as a submodule of my main project, but looking at other projects they don't usually have any submodule dependency, and it seems wrong to me to make people clone GTest as well as part of my project, as if they're already using it for their own unit tests they'll end up having duplicated code etc.

What's the common procedure for cases like this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: how the projects you’ve looked do unit-testing?

Comment: I've continued checking and it seems there are some cmake files that try to find the dependency installed in the system, so there's a 'FindGTest.cmake' that probably will do the work. I need to test it, and when I do so I'll come back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we put test under compilation flags (or cmake variable, or autotools configuration flag, or...) and disable compilation of test when the framework is not detected or not asked to be used by the person that compiles.

That way, the dependency is not required but the user has the ability to add it if he wishes to use the unit tests.

Comment: Yep. That's my idea: add a cmake flag that indicates if the user wants to generate the tests or not, but my question is more related to how to fix "when the framework is not detected". I think I found the solution using 'FindGTest.cmake' but I haven't had the time to try it yet. I'll come back with my results once I test it!

Comment: well, as I wrote, when not detected, just disable it. You may add a message indicating "Lib XXX not found; disabling use of lib XXX"